# Непонятный порядок выполнения asyncio-кода

Tags: python, asyncio

Играюсь с возможностями asyncio, в процессе появился такой код:

```
import asyncio

async def my_task():
    print('Старт')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('Я не должен выполняться')

async def go():
    asyncio.create_task(my_task())
    await asyncio.sleep(0.48)
    print('Хватит')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(go())
```

Я ожидаю, что `run_until_complete` завершится раньше, чем в таске успеет сработать `asyncio.sleep(0.5)`, и следовательно текст «Я не должен выполняться» не должен отпечататься.

По факту же `run_until_complete` продолжает работать даже ПОСЛЕ того, как `go()` завершился, и таск отрабатывает:

[image]

Почему? Что происходит? Я ожидаю, что после печати «Хватит» `run_until_complete` завершится, но вместо этого он передаёт управление в таск. Почему?

Я бы понял, если был недостаточно точный таймер, и вывод был бы такой:

```
Старт
Я не должен выполняться
Хватит
```

Но вывод явно не такой. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это будет немного сложновато, + не уверен что смогу все идеально описать и  обосновать, но думаю это будет хорошим началом.

В код для ясности внесем кое-какие изменения:

```
async def my_task():
    print(2, asyncio.all_tasks())
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print(4, asyncio.all_tasks())


async def go():
    time = 0.2
    asyncio.create_task(my_task())
    print(1, asyncio.all_tasks())
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    print(3, asyncio.all_tasks())

asyncio.run(go())
```

Также условимся использовать название **"основной поток"** и **"поток задач"** для разделения основной корутины и задачи запущенной из нее и **"список задач"** для вывода функции *asyncio.all_tasks()*.
Итак рассмотрим три случая:
***time = 0.2, time = 0.5, time = 0.8***

Начнем с простого: **time = 0.2**

```
1 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:13> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:4>>}
2 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:14> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f65a56827c8>()]> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:5>>}
3 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:15> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f65a56829a8>()]>>}
```

Список задач "1" говорит что у нас на выполнении две задачи:

1. Раньше поставленная на выполнение задача, которая ожидает своего часа
2. Основная задача, которую нужно обязательно доделать

*await asyncio.sleep(time)* - передает управление eventloop, он начинает выполнение поставленной ранее задачи, так как основной поток сейчас ждет выполнения какого-то действия(сна), о чем нам говорит список задач "2".

*await asyncio.sleep(0.5)* - опять передает управление eventloop, но делать ему пока нечего, так как и основной поток и поток задачи сейчас спят, теперь он просто ждет любого события ибо не закончив выполнение основного потока он не может остановится

И первым приходит ответ с основного потока, напоследок мы видим список задач "3", где мы видим что поток задачи чего-то ждет, а вот основной поток нечем не занят, и при таких условиях мы можем завершить выполнение основного потока, игнорируя все остальное.

Дальше: **time = 0.8**

```
1 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:12> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:3>>}
2 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:13> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f68e0db17c8>()]> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:4>>}
4 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:13> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f68e0db17c8>()]> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:6>>}
3 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:14> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>}
```

Здесь списки задач "1" и "2" идентичны и выполнение кода идет также. 
Отличия начинаются в момент когда eventloop ожидает любое событие от задач которые сейчас спят. На этот раз первым проснется поток задачи, так как у него ожидание всего 0.5 секунд.
Здесь мы увидим вывод списка задач "4", он говорит что основной поток пока что чем -то занят, а поток задачи в процессе выполнения, и нечего не помешает ему закончить свою работу. 
После завершения работы потока задачи eventloop опять берет все под контроль и ожидает нового события. Этим событием будет пробуждение главного потока, там мы увидим список задач "3" где больше нет потока задачи, а основной поток нечем не занят, и при таких условиях мы можем завершить выполнение основного потока.

И наконец: **time = 0.5**

```
1 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:12> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:3>>}
2 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:13> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7fc293c407c8>()]> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:4>>}
3 {<Task pending coro=<go() running at /opt/project/gff.py:14> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:150]>, <Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:5> wait_for=<Future finished result=None>>}
4 {<Task pending coro=<my_task() running at /opt/project/gff.py:6>>}
```

Тут ничего сложного, главное уследить за ходом выполнения кода и учесть одну важную деталь. 
Списки задач "1" и "2" опять ничем не отличаются, ход выполнения кода в этих местах не изменился, а вот в момент когда eventloop ожидает событие пока все спят кое-что изменилось. Когда время ожидания между двумя потоками почти одинаково, проснутся они тоже почти одновременно. И тут два пути, если первым проснется поток задачи, повторится сценарий 3, но если первым проснется основной поток то получится кое что странное на первый взгляд, но сначала нужно уточнить ту важную деталь о которой я упоминал раньше, eventloop не прекращает свою работу сразу по завершению основного потока, он еще должен завершить "тик", грубо говоря завершить все задачи которые были готовыми в момент остановки основного потока
В нашем случае туда в последний момент попала выполненная задача из потока задач (извини за тавтологию), об этом говорит список задач "3". И теперь, уже после завершения основного потока выполняется поток задачи, после чего eventloop прекращает свою работу.